# Problemas com OnChange no select?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho um evento do botão que aciona um ajax que carrega os dados como exemplo.

```
$('#table_com_parcelas tbody').append('<tr><td class="align">' + x + ' de ' + parcelas + '</td><td class="align">' + vencimento + '</td><td class="align">R$ ' + mascaraValor(valor.toFixed(2)) + '</td><td class="align"><select id="select-' + x + '" onchange="('+this.id+')>"' + insere_option() + '</select></td></tr>');
```

O ajax carrega de 1 a 12 selects, depende da quantidade de parcelas escolhida, porém o evento `onchange="('+this.id+')"` carraga o id do botão e não do select em questão.

existe alguma forma de inserir o `onchange()` após todos os selects terem sidos preenchidos? ou tem outra forma de selecionar o select que foi clicado

abaixo funções utilizadas;

```
while (x <= parcelas) {
        data_sun += 30;
        var vencimento = adicionarDiasData(data_sun, data);
        var valor = total / parcelas;
        $('#table_com_parcelas tbody').append('<tr><td class="align">' + x + ' de ' + parcelas + '</td><td class="align">' + vencimento + '</td><td class="align">R$ ' + mascaraValor(valor.toFixed(2)) + '</td><td class="align"><select id="select-' + x + '">' + insere_option() + '</select></td></tr>');
        x++;
    }//carrega os selects
type_of_payment();//chama a função que seta os outros selects. Aqui o onchange está funcionando.
```

Carraga options;

```
function insere_option() {
    var options = "";
    options += "<option value=''>Selecione</option>";
    options += "<option value='1'>Boleto</option>";
    options += "<option value='2'>Cartão</option>";
    options += "<option value='3'>Cheque</option>";
    options += "<option value='4'>Dinheiro</option>";
    options += "<option value='5'>Transferência</option>";
    return options;
}
```

Como todos são aninhados tenho outra função que seta os options subsequentes com a mesmo item selecionado.

```
function type_of_payment() {
    var selects = $("#table_com_parcelas select");
    var index = null;
    var valor = null;
    selects.on('change', function () {
        var valor = this.value;
        indice = selects.index(this);
        selects.each(function (index) {
            if (index > indice) {
                $(this).val(valor);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara pelo que entendi o problema é que o this que você está colocando está se referindo a um escopo diferente no caso a função do evento do botão, mude de `onchange="funcao('+this.id+')"` para `onchange="funcao(this.id)"`.

No seu código

1. Coloquei alguns valores estáticos para poder simular;
2. Removi as funções desconhecidas;
3. Adicionei:

onchange="teste(this.id)"

```
function teste(that){
   console.log(that);
}
```

```js
var x = 1;//para teste
var parcelas = 10;//para teste

while (x <= parcelas) {
  var vencimento = '2017-09-15'; //para teste
  var valor = 100; //para teste
        $('#table_com_parcelas tbody').append('<tr><td class="align">' + x + ' de ' + parcelas + '</td><td class="align">' + vencimento + '</td><td class="align">R$ ' + valor.toFixed(2) + '</td><td class="align"><select onchange="teste(this)" id="select-' + x + '">' + insere_option() + '</select></td></tr>');
        x++;
    }//carrega os selects
type_of_payment();

function teste(that){
  alert(that.value);
}

function type_of_payment() {
    var selects = $("#table_com_parcelas select");
    var index = null;
    var valor = null;
    selects.on('change', function () {
        var valor = this.value;
        indice = selects.index(this);
        selects.each(function (index) {
            if (index > indice) {
                $(this).val(valor);
            }
        });
    });
}

function insere_option() {
    var options = "";
    options += "<option value=''>Selecione</option>";
    options += "<option value='1'>Boleto</option>";
    options += "<option value='2'>Cartão</option>";
    options += "<option value='3'>Cheque</option>";
    options += "<option value='4'>Dinheiro</option>";
    options += "<option value='5'>Transferência</option>";
    return options;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_com_parcelas">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: eu tinha feito dessa forma que você mencionou porém o on("change",...) da função type_of_payment() deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Pode me explicar o que a  função type_of_payment deveria fazer?

Comment: Exemplo, o usuário seleciona o primeiro select com uma opção da forma de pagamento e a função seta os outros selects com a mesma forma de pagamento, caso seja feito em 5 parcelas e o primeiro for seleciona em cartão ele seta o restante como cartão também.

Comment: Pelo código da sua função ele vai setar tudo que tiver um índice maior que o alterado, execute o meu exemplo e veja como ele se comporta. se você quiser que alteração afete todos basta substituir o  if (index > indice) {
                $(this).val(valor);
            }  por $(this).val(valor);

Comment: sim exatamente isto ele deve alterar apenas os indices maiores, e isso está correto e no seu exemplo ele também está correto, mas queria criar um alert informando o valor que foi selecionado, e essa função o onchange não está chamando

Comment: Cara coloquei o alert com o valor selecionado..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65659/discussion-between-wagner-fernando-momesso-and-caique-romero).

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi solucionado inserindo

```
<script>
function func(id) {
    alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Na pagina de exibição do conteúdo, o mesmo não estava sendo reconhecido no `main.js` após o `ajax` popular os selects.